# Getting unauthorized_client response when creating social login with Microsoft using python package drf-msal-jwt

Tags: python, django, azure, outlook, django-socialauth

When trying to create social login with django and python package drf-msal-jwt using Azure I get the following error

[image: Error message on login]

I tried many ways. This is my apps manifest page is there anything i need to change.

```
{
"id": "1234567-1234-12l3-afe5-b01aa8cea588",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "de345rft-iok8-42hy-86bb-3124ahhgfts4d",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2020-12-14T12:06:13Z",
"description": null,
"certification": null,
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
"termsOfService": null,
"support": null,
"privacy": null,
"marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "app",
"notes": null,
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
"countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
"legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [
{
"customKeyIdentifier": null,
"endDate": "2024-12-14T12:09:51.944Z",
"keyId": "e1fe6rrr-ba31-4d61-89e7-12345iy5697j",
"startDate": "2022-12-14T12:09:51.944Z",
"value": null,
"createdOn": "2022-12-14T12:10:32.7193321Z",
"hint": "T9w",
"displayName": "secret"
}
],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "testemail@outlook.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
{
"url": "http://localhost:8000/",
"type": "Web"
},
{
"url": "http://localhost:5000/getAToken",
"type": "Web"
}
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
"resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639iy5697j",
"type": "Scope"
}
]
}
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

What i needed was when a new user visits our website we will be get a registration page with
a button with text "Sign in with Microsoft" and when the user clicks on this button
he will be redirected to a Microsoft login page,
where the user will give his Microsoft credentials(outlook email account credentials),
after that the user will be successfully signed in

For this purpose I wanted these API's

1. A GET API to get the redirect page link after the user clicks the "Sign in with Microsoft"
2. A POST API verify the code and state and get the access token
3. A POST API to get the refresh token

After Login with the response of the 1st API i get the above error.
What I want is that I want to login successfully.